# MISRA 2004 rule 8.3: Clarification

Tags: c, misra

I want to just clarify that following is a MISRA violation or not before using it in my code. I am calling one function from a file as under:

```
(void)Dem_SetEventStatus((Dem_EventIdType)(dtcFlt_t.dtc[dtcIndex]),DEM_EVENT_STATUS_FAILED);
```

Here `Dem_SetEventStatus` is defined in one header as under:

```
 extern FUNC(Std_ReturnType, RTE_CODE) Dem_SetEventStatus (Dem_ASR42_EventIdType EventId, Dem_ASR42_EventStatusType EventStatus);
```

Here `Dem_EventIdType` is a typedef of `unit8` and `Dem_ASR42_EventIdType` is `unsigned short`.

So , will there be the violation of MISRA 8.3?? how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 4):

This rule has nothing to do with calling functions.

MISRA-C:2004 Rule 8.3 is about defining and declaring functions, not calling them. It demands that the declaration and definition are identical, and the declaration must be in prototype format (8.1) with all parameter types specified and given names (16.3).

The real question here is: if you know that the function expects `Dem_ASR42_EventIdType` then why do you cast to a different type? That does not make sense. If you cast to mask out the lowest byte, then you should write your code in several steps:

```
Dem_EventIdType event_id = (Dem_EventIdType)dtcFlt_t.dtc[dtcIndex];
(void)Dem_SetEventStatus((Dem_ASR42_EventIdType)event_id, DEM_EVENT_STATUS_FAILED);
```

This isn't required by MISRA but by common sense.

Comment: I edited the code the way you have suggested but still i get an error for MISRA 8.3 saying that the symbol ´Dem_SetEventStatus´ is redeclared. My concern is solving MISRA violations as the previous version was also working properly.

Comment: @AnkitShah Sounds like your tool thinks that the function call is a function declaration. Either a tool bug and/or you forgot to include the relevant header.

Answer (score 0):

As Lundin advises, MISRA-C:2004 Rule 8.3 requires that the declaration and definition are identical... as such the example is not a violation of Rule 8.3

However the call of the function (as shown) is a violation of MISRA-C:2004 Rule 10.1 as it includes implicit type conversion.

Note: This issue is also being discussed on the (official) [MISRA Forum](https://www.misra.org.uk/forum/viewtopic.php?f=64&t=1714)

While casting should resolve the issue, it would be better to understand the underlying types of the variables, and (if appropriate) change the definitions to harmonise them.